# Primm's Algorithim in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, queue

I am working on a C++ project that will use Primm's algorithm to find the weight of a MST. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

const int maxVert = 'M' + 1;
const int maxAns = maxVert - 'A';

struct edgeType
{
    char vertex1, vertex2;
    int weight;
};

struct qType
{
    char vertex1, vertex2;
    int weight;
    qType* link;
};

enum colorType { white, gray, black };
colorType color[maxVert];

void init(int adj[maxVert][maxVert], colorType color[maxVert], edgeType ans[maxAns]);
void createGraph(int adj[maxVert][maxVert]);
void printGraph(int adj[maxVert][maxVert], ofstream& outf);
void createQueue(qType*& qHead, qType*& qTail);
bool emptyQueue(qType*& qHead, qType*& qTail);
void deQueue(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, char& vertex1, char& vertex2, int& weight);
void enQueue(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, char vertex1, char vertex2, int weight);
void mst(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, int adj[maxVert][maxVert], colorType color[maxVert], edgeType ans[maxAns], char startPoint, ofstream& outf);

int main()
{   
    ofstream outf("output.ot");
    int adj[maxVert][maxVert];
    edgeType ans[maxAns];
    qType* qHead;
    qType* qTail;

    init(adj, color, ans);
    createGraph(adj);
    outf << "2D Adjacency Matrix:" << endl;
    printGraph(adj, outf);
    createQueue(qHead, qTail);
    mst(qHead, qTail, adj, color, ans, 'A', outf);

    return 0;
}

void init(int adj[maxVert][maxVert], colorType color[maxVert], edgeType ans[maxAns])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxVert; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxVert; j++)
        {
            adj[i][j] = 0;
            adj[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxVert; i++)
    {
        colorType color = white;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxAns; i++)
    {
        ans->vertex1 = 0;
        ans->vertex2 = 0;
        ans->weight = 0;
    }
}

void createGraph(int adj[maxVert][maxVert])
{
    char vertex1, vertex2;
    int weight;
    fstream inf("input.dat");

    while (!inf.eof())
    {
        inf >> vertex1 >> vertex2 >> weight;
        adj[vertex1][vertex2] = weight;
        adj[vertex2][vertex1] = weight;
    }
}

void printGraph(int adj[maxVert][maxVert], ofstream& outf)
{   
    int i, j;

    outf << setw(5) << " ";
    for (j = 'A'; j < maxVert; j++)
    {
        outf << setw(3) << (char)j;
    }
    outf << endl;
    
    for (i = 'A'; i < maxVert; i++)
    {
        outf << setw(5) << char(i);
        for (j = 'A'; j < maxVert; j++)
        {
            outf << setw(3) << adj[i][j];
        }
        outf << endl;
    }
    outf << endl;
}

void createQueue(qType*& qHead, qType*& qTail)
{
    qHead = new qType;
    qTail = new qType;  

    qHead->vertex1 = 'A';
    qTail->vertex1 = 'A';
    qHead->vertex2 = 'A';
    qTail->vertex2 = 'A';
    qHead->weight = 0;
    qTail-> weight = 0;

    qHead->link = qTail;
    qTail->link = NULL;
}

bool emptyQueue(qType*& qHead, qType*& qTail)
{
    return qHead->link == qTail;
}

void deQueue(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, char& vertex1, char& vertex2, int& weight)
{
    qType *c;
    c = qHead->link;
    qHead->link = c->link;
    vertex1 = c->vertex1;
    vertex2 = c->vertex2;
    weight = c->weight;
    delete c;
}

void enQueue(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, char ivertex1, char ivertex2, int weight)
{
    qType* knew, * next, * previous;
    knew = new qType;
    knew->vertex1 = ivertex1;
    knew->vertex2 = ivertex2;
    knew->weight = weight;
    previous = qHead;
    next = qHead->link;

    while ((next != qTail) && (weight >= next->weight))
    {
        previous = next;
        next = next->link;
    }

    previous->link = knew;
    knew->link = next;
}

void mst(qType* qHead, qType* qTail, int adj[maxVert][maxVert], colorType color[maxVert], edgeType ans[maxAns], char startPoint, ofstream& outf)
{
    //char vertex1, vertex2;
    //int weight;
    int counter = 0;
    enQueue(qHead, qTail, startPoint, 'X', 0);
    color[qHead->vertex1] = gray;
    while (!emptyQueue(qHead, qTail))
    {
        deQueue(qHead, qTail, qHead->vertex1, qHead->vertex2, qHead->weight);

        if (color[qHead->vertex1]!=black && qHead->weight !=0)
        {
            ans[counter].vertex1 = qHead->vertex1;
            ans[counter].vertex2 = qHead->vertex2;
            ans[counter].weight = qHead->weight;
            counter++;

            for (qHead->vertex2 = 'A'; qHead->vertex2 > 'M'; qHead->vertex2++)
            {
                if (adj[qHead->vertex1][qHead->vertex2] != 0 && color[qHead->vertex2] != black)
                {
                    enQueue(qHead, qTail, qHead->vertex2, qHead->vertex1, adj[qHead->vertex1][qHead->vertex2]);
                    color[qHead->vertex2] = gray;
                }
            }
            color[qHead->vertex1] = black;
        }
    }   
    outf << ans->vertex1 << ans->vertex2 << ans->weight;
}
```

I am able to set up my adjacency matrix and assign weight values, but I am running into issues with my mst function. I'm not sure If I'm using the correct variables to pass to my queue. I'd like to be able to print out the edges and weights that span this tree but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd likely get (better) answers if you were able to narrow down the problem, so that people don't have to read pages of pages of code.

Comment: *"I am running into issues with my mst function."* -- I would propose that only the people who know what those issues are would be in a position to solve them. In this case, that information is not in the question, so you are the only person who knows what those issues are...